# Jquery img codigo para trocar

Tags: jquery, img

usei o codigo de um cara que o menu é de uma cor quando está no topo e quando o scroll da pagina desce, o menu fica preto, mas assim que ele ficar preto quero que a img que no caso é a logo, troque o src que está "logooficial.png" para "logooficial2.png" tem como me ajudar se souber ? obrigado =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery puro:

```
const window = $(window);
const logo = $('.logo');
window.scroll(function(){
   if( window.scrollTop < 100 )
      logo.attr('src', 'logooficial.png')
   else
      logo.attr('src', 'logooficial2.png')
});
```

Ou voce pode fazer tambem com auxilio do css

```
<style>
   .logo {
      background: url('logooficial.png')
   }
   .logo.scrolled {
      background: url('logooficial2.png')
   }
</style>
<script>
   const window = $(window);
   const logo = $('.logo');
   window.scroll(function(){
      if( window.scrollTop < 100 )
         logo.removeClass('.scrolled')
      else
         logo.addClass('.scrolled')
   });
</script>
```

Nesse segundo caso, a imagem nao deve ser setada com a tag  e sim com uma div e a imagem em background com css

Comment: meu codigo no script pro menu já está assim `      $(window).on("scroll", function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop()) {
                  $('nav').addClass('black');
            }

            else {
                  $('nav').removeClass('black');
            }
      })`   como faria pra acrescentar esse que vc falou ? obrigado desde já =) ta ajudando mt men

Comment: ` 
const logo = $('.logo');
$(window).on("scroll", function() { 
        if($(window).scrollTop()) { 
             logo.attr('src', 'logooficial.png');
             $('nav').addClass('black'); 
        } else {
            logo.attr('src', 'logooficial2.png');
            $('nav').removeClass('black'); 
        } 
})`

Acredito que acrescentaria assim.